# why curl is slower than request in browser

Tags: php, performance, curl

I have a curl like this:

```
    $t1 = time();
    exec('echo $t1 >> debug');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $service);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $t2 = time();
    exec('echo $t2 >> debug');
```

when i execute the url in browser it is fast enough. but this curl is much slower(about 20 seconds later). how can i make it as fast as the simple request?

also i have these results when i get the curl_getinfo:

```
     connect_time: 0.01   //on average
     total_time: 0.24      //on average
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Certainly it is not the cURL request itself taking that long, unless you have some very special return payload. Most likely it is the environment you implemented that request in that you want to take a closer look at. Without more information from your side it is impossible for us to help here.

Comment: i have logs before and after the curl and the time between them is 20 seconds, so what else can be if it is not curl fault?

Comment: What do you mean by "the logs"? Request entries in the access log file? That is not the time the cURL request takes! You have to time _only_ the request, obviously. Many examples for that on google. Also you can take a look at phps `tick` function which comes in handy for such tasks. The request itself takes the 0.24 seconds cURL tells you. Question is what else is happening in your program.

Comment: by logs i mean the exec('echo ----  >> debugfile ') command. the time between one before and one after the curl is long.

Comment: Why `exec()`? I thought the above is a part of some php file? Sorry, this does not lead anywhere. Post all of your code please, otherwise this is going to get a never ending story.

Comment: Are you using windows server, with `mysql` and `curl` extensions enabled ? Just asking.

Comment: apache server is used and yes they are enabled.

Comment: @arkascha of course it is part of php code. i use exec() just for debugging. i will add log lines.

Comment: Ah, so it is _not_ only the request time you measure, but all the setup and teardown too. And obviously also the time the server takes to respond is also contained. Network latencies too. You would have to compare the pure request time instead, compare it to a browser based request _from the same system_. Which most likely is not possible.

Comment: Is the code running on the same machine as the browser? A delay this long suggests a bad DNS server. You could easily verify this by capturing the network packets.